# Closure of bounded set is bounded? Topological space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be topological space, and $A \subseteq X$ that is bounded. Is the closure of $A$ also bounded?

This is true if $X$ is topological vector space, but is it if $X$ is only topological?

Comment: What is your definition of closure?

Comment: And how to define boundedness without a metric

Comment: Is this a metric space?

Comment: Closure is well defined for a general topological space.

Comment: @Yeah, I just wanted to know what he meant by closure in his course. So we could work with his definition to avoid wasting time when writing a proof. But as it stands boundedness is a metric property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is only topological, "bounded" has no meaning.

If $X$ is a metric space, the answer is "yes", as the closure consists of points that are within $\epsilon$ of points in the set.